# Why print function doesn't work in method: get_details() and None is returned for print(x.increment_odometer)?

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, attributes, return

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,make,model,year): 
        self.make=make
        self.model=model
        self.year=year
        self.odometer_reading=0 
        
    def get_details(self): #SELF allows access of attributes and methods of a class 
        details=print((f'The make is: {self.make}, the model is: {self.model}, & the year is: {self.year}\n'))
        #return details without print function works? i.w. details=rest of the line without print + return details (next line)
    
    def read_odometer(self): #reading the value (default)
        print(f'\nReading: {self.odometer_reading}')

        
    def update_odometer(self,mileage): 

        if mileage>=self.odometer_reading:
            print('\nReading has been changed')
            self.odometer_reading=mileage
        else:
            print('\nCan, not change ')
    def increment_odometer(self,miles):
        self.odometer_reading+=miles

x.get_details() #trying to modify print(x.get_details()) which does work. Why does print need to be supplied here? 

#incrementing the odometer 

print(x.increment_odometer(50)) #why is this none?
```

I am learning classes and am confused about some aspects:

1. Why is "return details" line needed for method get_details()? Normally a simple function call having def f(): print('a') works, hence the confusion.
2. print(x.increment_odometer(50)) is None. Perhaps a function return needed in increment_odometer() method?

**Confusing points having been commented in the code. Please englighten me.**

Sincerely.

Comment: the error is because you are assigning print() to an object.

Comment: object as in x?

Comment: in get_details function, you are assigning a print statement to the object _details_: "details=print"

Comment: I'm confused. I thought details was a variable. What differentiates one from the other?